# WAMP 2.4 - MYSQL instance Icon remains orange

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wampserver

I think my WampServer was inappropriately shut down. When i'm trying to start my wamp server, the icon remains orange. 
In mysql log, I have the following:

```
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 9777697745 and 9777697745 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 9838673424 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-02-29 10:14:56 3548 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-02-29 10:14:56 135c  InnoDB: File operation call: 'read' returned OS error 0.
2016-02-29 10:14:56 135c  InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I have already tried the following:

1 - add row innodb_force_recovery = 1 in my.ini file.

2 - changed mysql port from 3306 to 3307

3 - already added some flush things just below innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50 in my.ini

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing all these which didnt worked, Luckily i had already backed-up my data folder. I just deleted the actual data folder n replaced it by the back-up. I restarted everything and it is working.